# Ubuntu virtual terminal not working

Tags: 20.04, virtual-console

I am unable to open the virtual terminals by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Fn`. All I see is the cursor flashing in the top right corner and the ubuntu loading circle in the bottom of the screen.

Edit: I found out that if i execute `sudo systemctl stop plymouth-quit-wait.service` I am able to access the virtual terminal, but the loading animation is still there.

Please Help.